# minidom.parseString Error

Tags: python, xml

I get this error while parsing my **xml** data to prettify it :

```
File "script.py", line 97, in buildXML
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(clean_xml)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1931, in parseString
    return expatbuilder.parseString(string)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 940, in parseString
    return builder.parseString(string)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 223, in parseString
    parser.Parse(string, True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: unbound prefix: line 5, column 109
```

My code :

```
items = ET.Element("items")

title = SubElement(item, "title")
title.text = incident.title

clean_xml = ET.tostring(items, 'utf-8')
reparsed = minidom.parseString(clean_xml)
clean_xml = reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="  ")
```

Comment: This is all of your Traceback text?

Comment: Resolved. I just had a spacename to remove.